# Traversing a non-standard object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am working with an API returning a response to me via AJAX, it returns the response in `responseJSON` so I access the part of the object I need with dot notation just like with any other AJAX call

```
var test = jqxhr.responseJSON.test;
```

A literal representation of the object would be:

```
test = {1_status: "invalid", 4_type: "domain.com", 1_type: "alpha.domain.com", 4_email: "admin@domain.com", 3_email: "admin@charlie.domain.com"…}
```

Which appears as so in the console after a `console.log(test)`

```
1_email: "admin@alpha.domain.com"
1_status: "invalid"
1_type: "alpha.domain.com"
2_email: "admin@bravo.domain.com"
2_status: "invalid"
2_type: "bravo.domain.com"
3_email: "admin@charlie.domain.com"
3_status: "invalid"
3_type: "charlie.domain.com"
4_email: "admin@domain.com"
4_status: "invalid"
4_type: "domain.com"
errorCode: "0"
```

How would I access the values by key like `1_email` in a `for` loop interation like below.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
  // access key values here like so:
  //console.log(test.i_email);
  // where the console should return admin@alpha.domain.com on the first interation
}
```

If I simply do something like the below outside the loop where I manually call a certain key:

```
console.log(test.1_email);
```

I get the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I need to access each piece with [i]_status as I do not know the exact return values and the order changes, and unfortunately I do not have access to the API directly.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with an indexer.

```
test[i + '_email']
```

Comment: That works perfectly, I have never used `indexing` outside of `test[i]` so I didn't even think of that. Thanks a Ton :)

Comment: In javascript `x[y]` is not indexing. It's property access.